# What factors are held constant for a speaker playing at constant volume and frequency?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics

Consider a speaker set to play at 50% volume. It is playing a sound with constant frequency of 1500Hz. If I increase that frequency to 3000Hz how is the intensity affected?
I found the equation intensity is proportional to frequency squared on http://physics.info/intensity/ can this be shown experimentally or are there mechanisms in the speaker to counteract the increase in frequency? I thought perhaps the energy output of a speaker is constant hence power and intensity will be as well however this may be wrong.